# Android app Attempt to invoke virtual method error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

My android webview fragment app is getting crashed, after i have added a button to go from one fragment to another, the error on the console is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ahmed.stories, PID: 11846
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ahmed.stories.MainActivity.setUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.ahmed.stories.Saying$3.onPageStarted(Saying.java:127)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageStarted(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:517)
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:144)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

It says the problem is with line 127 which is with `((MainActivity) getActivity()).setUrl(url);` but i can't find anything wrong with it, am  ew to android and trying to learn, may be you guys can help.

```
private void initWebView() {
        home_web.setWebChromeClient(new Saying.MyWebChromeClient(getActivity()));
        home_web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setUrl(url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                home_web.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    TextView home_tv, stories, bookmarks, drafts, fakecheck, lost, leaving;
    CardView lyt_top_bar;
    View toolbar_line;
    BottomNavigationView navigation;

    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Home home = new Home();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, home, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_search:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Search search = new Search();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, search, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_edit:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Edit edit = new Edit();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, edit, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_message:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Notification notification = new Notification();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, notification, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;


                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Profile profile = new Profile();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, profile, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
         navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navigation));

        bookmarks = findViewById(R.id.bookmarks);
        stories = findViewById(R.id.stories);
        home_tv = findViewById(R.id.home_tv);
        lyt_top_bar = findViewById(R.id.lyt_top_bar);
        toolbar_line = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_line);

        stories.setOnClickListener(this);
        home_tv.setOnClickListener(this);
        bookmarks.setOnClickListener(this);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Home home = new Home();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, home, "Home");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main3, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            shareTextUrl();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        showSystemUI();
        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Profile profile = new Profile();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, profile, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Edit edit = new Edit();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, edit, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Drafts drafts = new Drafts();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, drafts, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fakecheck fakecheck = new Fakecheck();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fakecheck, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_lost) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Lost lost = new Lost();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, lost, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Leaving leaving = new Leaving();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, leaving, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {

        lyt_top_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         navigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar_line.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public void showSystemUI() {
        lyt_top_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbar_line.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
//        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
//                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
//        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showSystemUI();
        if (v == home_tv) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Saying saying = new Saying();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, saying, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            saying.hideProgress();
            hideSystemUI();
        }

        if (v == bookmarks) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Bookmarks bookmarks = new Bookmarks();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, bookmarks, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == drafts) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Drafts drafts = new Drafts();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, drafts, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == fakecheck) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fakecheck fakecheck = new Fakecheck();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fakecheck, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == lost) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Lost lost = new Lost();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, lost, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == leaving) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Leaving leaving = new Leaving();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, leaving, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (v == stories) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Trending trending = new Trending();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, trending, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
    String urlOpen="";
    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.urlOpen = url;
    }
    public void shareTextUrl(){
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
        // what to do with it.
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlOpen);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "We Only share with the people we care!"));
    }
    public void goToHome(){
        showSystemUI();
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Home home = new Home();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, home, "Home");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you attach the fragment to the `Activity`? your `getActivity` is returning `null`

Comment: @TamHuynh i have updated the code with my MainActivity, please have a look

Comment: Where in the method `initWebView` called? Is it called from the `Fragment`'s onCreateView?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, or any new code you'd tried would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since someone has answered there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.